# How to set Custom object Id through could code Parse.com

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I'm using Parse server 3.10 which is hosted by Back4app. I've enabled the option to allow custom Id in the server custom settings, `{"allowCustomObjectId": true}`, and now i'm able to set the custom Id of an object through an API call like this.

```
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATIONID"
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REST_KEY" 
--data-urlencode "{"objectId":"xWMyZ4YEGZ","name":"Nat"}" 
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Test
```

But I need to set it through cloud code , right now i'm trying to do something like this but this is not working.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setId",async (request) => { 
        const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
        const gameScore = new GameScore();

        gameScore.set("objectId", "8YgwDJ19qX");
        gameScore.set("name","nat");
        return await gameScore.save(null,{useMasterKey:true});
});
```

When I try to run this cloud function this is the error that I get.

```
{
    "code": 101,
    "error": "Object not found."
}
```

Looking forward to solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems at this current time it is not possible to set custom ID through cloud code using JavaScript. A workaround for this is using REST API through cloud code like so:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createObjectId", async (request) => {
    //Your custom id
    const objectId = "8YgwDJ18qX";
    //Your Class name and another optional class variable
    const { nameClass, propertyName } = request.params;
    //Make sure to define these environment variables in your server's env file
    const { APPLICATION_ID,  REST_KEY, SERVER_URL } = process.env;
    //Finally call hit the api.
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${SERVER_URL}/classes/${nameClass}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'X-Parse-Application-Id':APPLICATION_ID,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':REST_KEY
        },
        body: {
            objectId: objectId,
            name: propertyName
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Far from an ideal way to set a custom objectId. Should be changed on Parse. But this works so thank you!

Comment: I should warn you, that I stopped using this because after a while I was getting inconsistent results and my instance on back4app was broken. For example, after save triggers weren't working correctly, some objects were having weird IDs like '3921jfakfjdiqjdfjl10fj1' and so on and so forth. So please use it at your own risk

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will test it thoroughly before going into production